# How do I make an image an object so that I can build it once and then just keep using it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found this code example on actually this site, but then could not find it again. I have been working with it for a couple of nights. I want to make the pacman smaller and then be able to make it a image or object that I can rotate around and flip directions. Is this possible with this type of drawing.

I  tried making all of the integer values half thinking that would make the pacman smaller and it did not and gave me a funny looking circle with no eye.

**Question: How do you make this an image that can be move around and do have to have  ctx.beginPath(); in the code?**

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chapter 2 Example 28: Animating a Path</title>
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>

<body>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
 Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
</canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


   function eventWindowLoaded() {
        var theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0.25 * Math.PI, 1.25 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0.75 * Math.PI, 1.75 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 75, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
        ctx.fill();
    }
        eventWindowLoaded();    
</script> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your pacman on a separate offscreen canvas.

Then you can draw that canvas to your visible canvas using drawImage.

- draw it larger
- draw it smaller
- rotate it
- animate it.

A Demo including animation:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/j2cNw/

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: white; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red; background-color:blue;}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw your pacman to an offscreen canvas
    var pac=makePacCanvas();

    // draw it on the visible canvas
    ctx.drawImage(pac,10,10);

    // make it smaller (50x50px)
    ctx.drawImage(pac,110,10,50,50);

    // make it larger (150x150px)
    ctx.drawImage(pac,10,125,150,150);

    // rotate it 60 degrees
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(225,200);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI/3);  // PI/3==60 degrees 
    ctx.drawImage(pac,-50,-50);
    ctx.restore();


    function makePacCanvas(){

        var pacCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        var pacCtx=pacCanvas.getContext("2d");

        pacCanvas.width=100;
        pacCanvas.height=100;

        pacCtx.beginPath();
        pacCtx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0.25 * Math.PI, 1.25 * Math.PI, false);
        pacCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
        pacCtx.fill();

        pacCtx.beginPath();
        pacCtx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0.75 * Math.PI, 1.75 * Math.PI, false);
        pacCtx.fill();

        pacCtx.beginPath();
        pacCtx.arc(50, 25, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        pacCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
        pacCtx.fill();

        return(pacCanvas);
    }

    var x=200;
    var direction=1;
    animate();

    function animate(){

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        ctx.clearRect(175,0,300,100);
        if(direction==1){
            ctx.drawImage(pac,x,10,20,20);
        }else{
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(x+10,20);
            ctx.scale(-1,1);
            ctx.drawImage(pac,0,-10,20,20);
            ctx.restore();       
        }

        x+=direction;
        if(x<190 || x>300-20){ direction*=-1; }

    }


}; // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>All pacmen are drawn using 1 offscreen canvas<br>as source for drawImage</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see the animation moving on my screen from the above code. Is there something different about this code and your sample code on your page. Or does my Google Chrome not support that, which is hard for me to believe. Does the $(function(){}); is that J Query code can you paste up the code with no JQuery. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome!  The image above is just an image.  Click the demo link to see the animation.  I also edited the code above to include the animation. ;-)  jQuery is not needed at all in this code...you can substitute window.onload = function() { ... } if you want.  I use jQuery in all my apps since it does a fantastic job of smoothing out browser inconsistencies.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: makePacCanvas() --- How does the make a off screen canvas image. Doesn't it use part of the canvas that is declared in the Body of the HTML page.

Comment: In makePacCanvas, the offscreen canvas is created with: var pacCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");  That offscreen canvas holds the source pacman "image" which is then manipulated and drawImage'd to the visible canvas (the visible canvas is created in the html body) Cheers! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
```

This will allow you to grab the image data on the canvas and re-use it or manipulate it.

So for example, you can draw your image onto the canvas, then grab the image data and store it for future use.

**EDIT:**

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); // this is not added to the DOM
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// insert code to draw onto ctx, then get data
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
// now you have the data, you can manipulate it/add it to other canvases
// whenever you want, i.e.
var pageCanvasCtx = document.getElementById("#canvas").getContext("2d");
pageCanvasCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Is this the only way. Can you draw the image into a variable before it gets to the image. Is there a list of all attributes of ctx that will show all of the attributes.

Comment: @user3376708 You can draw into a canvas that is not yet added to the DOM, for example (i.e. before you `appendChild`). For a reference on context you can check out the w3 html5 draft (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/) or http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_canvas.asp